# Unable to summon object with this command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a floor crafting system but the summon command won't work. I put it in a separate command block to troubleshoot, I fixed a few minor bugs, but then the output just said "unable to summon object" I don't know what's wrong, here's the command I'm using:

```
/summon minecraft:item ~0 ~1 ~0 {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",Damage:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Nether Crafter",Lore:["This crafter uses the power of the nether","to fuse items"]},ench:[{}],crafter:1b}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a `Count` to your item, otherwise it defaults to 0 which is not valid:

```
/summon minecraft:item ~0 ~1 ~0 {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:1b,Damage:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Nether Crafter",Lore:["This crafter uses the power of the nether","to fuse items"]},ench:[{}],crafter:1b}}}
```

You may also want to remove `Damage:1`, or it'll show up as a black/magenta square.

Comment: I like black/magenta squares

Comment: is not work is say to me unabel to summon object I'm in 1.7.10 in server aternose